# setting black/grey color scheme for ggplot2?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

How can I set a black/grey/dark color scheme for ggplot2 (analogous to "theme_bw") for ggplot2, without manually specifying the color?  i.e. have something like:

```
ggplot(mtcars) + geom_boxplot(aes(factor(cyl), mpg, fill=factor(gear)))
```

generate black/grey boxplots (equispaced in that scale as usual) instead of red/green/blue?

thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
last_plot() + scale_fill_grey()
```